# How Reset Password using angular 7 with webAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, passwords, reset

I wanted to generate a reset password link to send to the user's email that will open the ResetPassword page. On this page I will fill in the details regarding the new password and then confirm the password.

Any how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download sample from ASP.NET Identity for Password recovery/reset.

Write API with email input and send to email an reset link base on sample.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

After that you create a service in angular to call web api with email input.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
resetpassword(email: string){
    return this.http.get('/api/user/resetpassword?email=' + email)
      .map(response => {
        // handle logic here
  });
  }
}
```